# Why Maven project is tied to J2SE-1.5 by default?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

If I create default empty based on no archetype `Maven` project in `Eclipse`, it will be based on `J2SE-1.5`.

[image]

I am to change manually both Build Path entry and code compliance.

Why?

How to make it be other?

Comment: Check your installed JRE's, and which JRE maven is configured to use under Windows > preferences.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539139/what-causes-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse-to-use-java-1-5-instead-of-java-1-6-b/43210342#43210342

Comment: @Taylor from the link above (accepted answer) it seems you're not right: "The m2eclipse plugin doesn't use Eclipse defaults, the m2eclipse plugin derives the settings from the POM."

Comment: @Line if OP is creating a default `default empty based on no archetype Maven project in Eclipse` then there is no pom.

Comment: @Taylor but it's cretaed. The defaults point (now already) to 1.6, as defined here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html.

Answer (score 17):

@axtavt is right, add source level configuration to your project. But do not configure `maven-compiler-plugin`, simply put this properties into `pom.xml`.

```
<properties> 
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source> 
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties>
```

After this refresh maven configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: It is no sense to put settings into `pom.xml`. `pom.xml` appears only AFTER project is already created and AFTER java 1.5 is already set. I would not go to `pom.xml` since I would just go to `Build Path` configuration and change java version there. I need some PRESET configuration, so that NEW files will be java 7 based, i.e. BEFORE project `pom.xml` created.

Comment: Your settings worked in `MYMAVEN/conf/settings.xml` file, while I don't see if it is possible to put plugin code @axtavt suggested there

Comment: Put this properties into `pom.xml` and **reimport** maven project from Eclipse.

Comment: So you suggest (1) create Eclipse project, (2) edit `pom.xml`, (3) reimort? These are 3 steps. I want one: (1) create Eclipse project. So that it be already 1.7

Comment: Add this information to question, or better ask another question :)  I'm not using Eclipse anymore (IntelliJ is much better), so I can help you with one step configuration. My answer describes Maven configuration, Eclipse is just a tool, you can use this project without Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm... My question is definitely about Eclipse and tagged appropriately.

Comment: Your question is *How to make it be other?*. Fix pom.xml and reimport and this is done :) This is common pattern for doing this, creating project is not very often task :)

Comment: This answers "how to fix it" part, but not "why is that". Could you please add this part by mentioning it's derived in POM and pointing out to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html site, which say what is default value for source and target values?

Answer (score 7):

It's consistent with `source` and `target` settings of [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html), which are `1.5` by default.

If you change them, generated project will use different version of as well:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <source>1.7</source>
         <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that if you change compliance settings of Eclipse project without changing of `maven-compiler-plugin` settings, your Maven builds would be inconsistent with your Eclipse environment.

Comment: To `<plugins>` section of your `pom.xml`. If your Eclipse project is already generated, click `Update project` after adding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that newly created projects in Eclipse use another default java version than Java 1.5, you can change the configuration in the maven-compiler-plugin.

- Go to the folder .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1
- Open maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.jar with a zip program.
- Go to META-INF/maven and open the plugin.xml
- In the following lines:
  <source implementation="java.lang.String" default-value="1.5">${maven.compiler.source}</source>
  <target implementation="java.lang.String" default-value="1.5">${maven.compiler.target}</target>
- change the default-value to 1.7 or 1.8 or whatever you like.
- Save the file and make sure it is written back to the zip file.

From now on, all new Maven projects use the java version you specified.

Information is from the following blog post: https://sandocean.wordpress.com/2019/03/22/directly-generating-maven-projects-in-eclipse-with-java-version-newer-than-1-5/